# I push an object to my Array in mongoose, array only stores its length

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to push an object into an Array in mongoose, but whenever i do it, it puts its length like this(mongoose, the attribute is schoolComment at the bottom), I am using mlab.com for database.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58e17ee3e24dfb1f70d76460"
    },
    "schoolName": "Koc Universitesi",
    "schoolIlce": "Sariyer",
    "schoolSehir": "Istanbul",
    "schoolId": 981299,
    "__v": 5,
    "schoolComments": [
        3
    ]
}
```

this is my code in node JS (The comments are not appearing in html because of this reason)

```
app.post('/comment', function(req, res){
  if(req.session.user && req.session){
    User.findOne({email: req.session.user.email}, function(err, user){
    if(err) {
      res.send('error');
    }
    if(user){
      if(req.session.user.password === user.password){
        var thisID = user.userid;
        Universite.findOne({schoolName: req.body.collegeName}, function(err, college){
            if(err) res.send('error');
            if(college){
              college.set({schoolComments: college.schoolComments.push({thisID: req.body.comment})}).save(function(err){
                if(err){
                  res.render('errors', {error:'Error'});
                }else{
                  res.locals.college = college;
                  res.locals.user = user;
                  res.render('universiteinfoUser');
                }
              });
            }
        });
      }else{
        res.render('login', {});
      }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and this is HTML DOM Form for it. The comments are not appearing because of this reasons.

```
<form onkeypress="enterPress();" action="/comment" method="post">
          <textarea maxlength="100" style="font-size: 25px;" name="comment" rows="3" cols="50" placeholder="Yorumunuzu yazin..."></textarea><br>
          <input style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" type="text" name="collegeName" value="<%=college.schoolName%>"></input>
          <button type="submit" name="commentSubmit">Comment Submit</button>
        </form>
          <div class="userCommentDisplay">
            <ul>
              <%college.schoolComments.forEach(function(item, i){%>
                  <%var k = college.schoolComments[i]%>
                  <%for(key in k){%>
                    <%if(key === user.userid){%>
                      <li><%=k[key]%> Same</li>
                    <%}else{%>
                      <li><%=k[key]%></li>
                    <%}%>
                  <%}%>
              <%})%>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) and build your comment item dynamically (to set the dynamic field name) :

```
var item = {};
item[user.userid] = req.body.comment;

Universite.findOneAndUpdate({
    schoolName: req.body.collegeName
}, {
    $push: {
        "schoolComments": item
    }
}, { new: true }, function(err, college) {
    if (err) {
        res.render('errors', { error: 'Error' });
    } else {
        res.locals.college = college;
        res.locals.user = user;
        res.render('universiteinfoUser');
    }
});
```

Note that I've aded `{ new: true }` in order to return the modified document `college` instead of the unaltered one.

FYI, in your code, you have used JS method [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) that will return the new length of the array by using `college.schoolComments.push`

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now. It was definitely about the prototype